# D3: modifying stored data values

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This may be a really dumb question, but in D3 is it possible to modify stored data values via a function?

For example:

```
var data = [ 1 ];

$(document).ready(function repeat() { data[]+1.each('end', repeat); };
```

essentially I am trying to call a function to modify the existing stored data.

Would it have to be bound to an object to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Are you trying to edit your data before binding to a DOM element?  Or are you trying to update the data bound to DOM elements?

Comment: Your doesn't make sense to me I'm afraid, but if you want to modify the data bound to DOM elements you can use `selection.each(function(d) { d +=1});`

Comment: I was more or less just curious if it could be done: Was curious if you could store and modify data outside of a DOM attribute.

Edit: I don't know if it would have any practical application, more just poking the system.